# Return a string representation of an attribute in another model Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have two models, and if I try the get method on postman for the products, I can only see the product category by ID and I want to see it as text. Any ideas on how to do that?
Edit: Added the StringRelatedField that was suggested in the answer below but it seems to be readonly, when I try to edit the product, it gets me a new error: `` NotImplementedError: StringRelatedField.to_internal_value() must be implemented for field . If you do not need to support write operations you probably want to subclass `ReadOnlyField` instead. `` Any ideas how to solve this?

To clarify:
what i get in postman:

```
name: ball,
default_price: 100,
product_cateogry: 1
```

what i want to get:

```
name:ball,
default_price:100,
product_category: sports
```

The model

```
class Product_category(models.Model):    

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    default_price = models.FloatField(max_length=10)
    product_category = models.ManyToManyField(Product_category, related_name="products")
```

Serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_category = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'default_price', 'description', 'deleted','product_category']
```

Comment: A `Product` can belong to *multiple* `Category`s.

Comment: In which case I'd have to display all the category names, but how would i do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the `__str__` to join the names of the categories together with:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        la = f'name:{self.name},'
        lb = f'default price: {self.default_price}'
        lc = ', '.join(str(s) for s in self.product_category.all())
        return f'{la}\n{lb}\n{lc}'
```

For the serializer, we can work with a [**`StringRelatedField`** [DRF-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield):

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_category = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'default_price', 'description', 'deleted', 'product_category']
```

or you can use the serializer in both the read and the write direction with the [**`SlugRelatedField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='name',
        many=True,
        queryset=Product_category.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'default_price', 'description', 'deleted', 'product_category']
```

Comment: @SikeYouTh: you should implement the `__str__` of the `Product` model, not the `Product_category`...

Comment: @SikeYouTh: if you work with postman, you likely work with a serializer? Can you share the serializer by editing the question?

Comment: @SikeYouTh: see the edit for the serializer.

Comment: sorry to bother you again mate, here's the problem, if i use my method to update, it's getting me an error that says, "field 'id' expected a number but got 'sports'" any idea what to do about that? From a quick read online, this StringRelatedField seems to be only readable, but i want to write to it aswell.

Comment: Updated the main question with the error that I get when I use that piece of code, any help would be more than welcome!

Comment: @SikeYouTh: what if you use a `SlugRelatedField` as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: I'm getting this error now: ```AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.``` From what I read on the slugfield documentation that you linked, it says "queryset - The queryset used for model instance lookups when validating the field input. Relationships must either set a queryset explicitly, or set read_only=True."

Comment: @SikeYouTh: ah yes, you need to specify the queryset, see edit.

Comment: Did that while I looked at the documentation, meant to edit sooner but I couldn't. The problem is that in my table, it's taken away my ability to update/create products, they're both giving 400 bad request on my console in the web app, in my postman it's giving me object with name=Sports (which is the name of the category) does not exist. Tried putting the ID like before, still getting the same error, object with name=1 does not exist.

Comment: @SikeYouTh: you need to import the `Product_category` model in your serializers. It will then use the `name` field to determine the corresponding ojbects.

Comment: Righttt, awesome man. I'm confused about one more thing though, in postman, both edit and create work perfectly, in my web interface (using angular), the edit works fine, the create still gets me a 400 bad request. you think it might be something in the frontend instead?

Comment: If these both work at Postman, then yes, likely there is something wrong. You can perhaps look at the network console, and copy the request Angular made, and compare it with the request made by Postman (and look for differences with the headers, body, etc.).